# tidyverse across where(!is.factor)?

Tags: tidyverse, across

I would like to create factor variables for all non-factor columns. I tried:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(across(where(!is.factor), as.factor, .names = "{.col}_factor"))
```

But get error message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(where(!is.factor), as.factor, .names = "{.col}_factor")`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! invalid argument type
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

the `where()` function needs to be written as a formula, which in tidyverse shorthand is:

```
  dat %>%
      mutate(across(where(~!is.factor(.x)), as.factor, .names = "{.col}_factor"))
```